# convert SQL string into a date that can be queried

Tags: sql, sybase

I am pulling from a database using the following:

```
SELECT
ID, CUSTOMER, NAME, etc, etc, TERM_INDEX
FROM "DAB055.ADT" DAB055
```

Now I want to limit the date range we pull, so would like to do something like:

```
WHERE TERM_INDEX >= '01.01.2015'
```

but the output in that field looks like:

```
20150629W
```

How can I convert that into a usual date field within the same statement, so that it can be filtered on?

Thanks.

Comment: it's a small german ERP system, so....  not sure!! I can just run SQL queries via a control panel. It usually works fine. Its just this one table has the date written like this (text I guess).... which causes the problem.

Comment: What datatype is the column 'TERM_INDEX'?

Comment: the DBMS is SQL-Datenbank "Advantage Database Server" von Sybase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your dates are stored in a format that will sort chronologically by using the alphabetical order. You can probably just say `WHERE TERM_INDEX >= '20150101'`.

Also it shouldn't be difficult to grab the first 8 characters and convert to a date type. Without knowing which platform you're on we'd have to guess at the syntax though.

One of these might work to figure out what your database server is:

```
select @@version
select * from v$version
```

Comment: thanks. Those didn't work... but the error messages include: [iAnywhere Solutions][Advantage SQL][ASA].. if that helps? According to some info I found, its SQL-Datenbank "Advantage Database Server" von Sybase.

Comment: I've used ASA and it can be weird. Did you try the where clause?

Comment: thanks. just doing the sort as you mention is the easiest work around!

Comment: Since it's ASA I think it might be faster as well.